# Where to validate method's arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm wondering, where - and how often - in the code validate method's arguments.

In the example class below (a .dll library), what do you think is the best way? Suppose I want to validate, that some object cannot be `null` (but it can be any other validation required for method to run properly). Is it better to check it only once  in point 1., in public method avaible for user, and later "trust myself", that in other, private, methods it will not be null or, better be a little paranoid and check it every time it's going to be used (in points 2. 3. and 4.)

Checking it just before using the object (in points 2, 3, 4) protects me in the future, if I decide to change something in the class, using these private methods, and "forget" to pass valid object. Also I don't have to remember about validation if I add some new public method in the future. On the other hand - it's checking for the same condition over and over again. Or maybe you have some other suggestions?

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public void ProcessObject(SomeObject obj)
    {
        //1. if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentException("You must provide valid object.");

        DoSomething(obj);
        DoMore(obj);
        DoSomethingElse(obj);
    }

    private void DoSomething(SomeObject obj)
    {
        //2. if (obj == null) throw new ArgumenException("You must provide valid object.");
        //do something with obj...
    }

    private void DoMore(SomeObject obj)
    {
        //3. if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentException("You must provide valid object.");
        //do something with obj...
    }

    private void DoSomethingElse(SomeObject obj)
    {
        //4. if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentException("You must provide valid object.");
        //do something with obj..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's an API that you're exposing for other developers to consume, then on each of your methods you should indeed throw either `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentNullException`.

If it's internal classes or methods that other developers will not be interacting with directly, I would use `Debug.Assert`, so in debug mode you get additional debugging information, and in release mode it gets nopped away and you receive the performance benefit of not doing all these argument checks everywhere.

Comment: You probably want SuperAssert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188701.aspx

Answer (score 5):

In a good software design methods need to be independant from each other.
You must be able to use them in any order and separated from each other. So yes you have to check the same condition in all of the methods over and over again.

**Edit:**
I would use CodeContract with a Pre-Condition that checks that obj is not null. Since this seems to be a pre-condition for the methods to work correctly.

Comment: That how I was thinking as well, but it seems to be in opposite to other answers... Let's wait for other opinions.

Answer (score 3):

Each public method should validate its input.

Private methods can rely IMHO on validation of other public methods in the class if you're just passing a previously validated object. Since private methods are encapsulated in the class the responsibility of validation stays in the class.

However, if you have a private method that takes some calculated parameters (not the ones passed to the public method), than additional validation should be in place.

Your unit tests will be testing public interface of the class, and they will fail if your `SomeObject` is `null` if your validation is only in `ProcessObject`. In that case I wouldn't duplicate validation in private methods.